# Calculating occurrences in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the number of occurrences of a character in a string,

I've tried

```
length(grep("3", "987654332")[[1]])
```

`[1] 1`

It doesn't calculate the second occurrence of "3".

I also tried

```
length(gregexpr("0", "98765432")[[1]])
```

`[1] 1`

This calculate the multiple occurrences fine, but returns 1 for non occurring values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `gregexpr` returns `-1` when there is no match, you can do:

```
> sum(gregexpr("3", "3398765432")[[1]] != -1)
[1] 3
> sum(gregexpr("0", "3398765432")[[1]] != -1)
[1] 0
```